# Newbie. Custom class

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, alloc

`CustomClass *variableName = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
variableName.propertyName = @"Some text";`

Could anyone explain this code step by step in human language?

Why if I want to send data to a property in `CustomClass` I am accessing it throught `varibaleName.propertyName` , but not through `CustomClass.propertyName`. 
I can not understand it.

If I want to send some data to a varibale in `CustomClass` wouldn't it be logically to show the path to that property = `CustomClass.propertyName = @"Some text";` ?

`*variableName` - what is it for?

I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion on the difference between an instance and a class. It's generally better to try and link complex ideas like this to real-world examples.

A **Class** could, for example, be Cars. Thus, you have a Car class. It will include information shared by all Cars. For example, instead of having propertyName it could have a "model" name. To access data about any given car you must first create it. That is what you do in the first line: `CustomClass *variableName = [[CustomClass alloc] init];`

In our example, we would write `Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] init];` which creates a new Car object that we call `myCar`. Then, you can say `myCar.model = "Civic"`. We do not want to make **all** cars be a "Civic", but specifically the `myCar` that we created.
Do not be confused between a Class, which describes a general kind of object, and an Instance, which is the object itself.

Hopefully you now understand the last part of your question:

> *variableName - what is it for?

This means that you have a reference to an instance of your `CustomClass` which is called `variableName`. In our example, this is `myCar` which you can then manipulate or change.

Comment: `Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] init];` - creates a new Car object with the name myCar. But if it is: `Car myCar = [[DifferentCar alloc] init];` What will be the difference? I know that `[[XX alloc] init];` is for creating a new object, but what XX does there?

Comment: @Edgar others may also be confused by this. Go ahead and ask this in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You access `variableName.propertyName` instead of `CustomClass.propertyName` because `variableName` is an instance of the class, while `CustomClass` is the class itself, not the object that you use.

For instance, you have 2 `CustomClass` objects, lets say `variable1` and `variable2`. `variable1.propertyName` will be different from `variable2.propertyName` because they are different instances of the class, not the class itself.